# How to alter a date field into a specific format

Tags: date, sql-server-2012, ms-access-2010

I have a field called GR date.  The values look like this:

20171031
20170922
20170803
20170707
20170626

I want to manipulate the values into a new field in a specific format.  The new field is called Reporting Period and the values would look like this:

10 2017
9 2017
8 2017
7 2017
6 2017

I have the Access code to create the field, but I am trying to do this in T-SQL and the DateSerial and Mid functions do not work in there.  How can I re-write this?

```
Reporting Period: Month(DateSerial(Left([GR Date],4),Mid([GR Date],5,2),Right([GR Date],2))) & " " & Year(DateSerial(Left([GR Date],4),Mid([GR Date],5,2),Right([GR Date],2)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in SQL Server, use this:

```
Select Cast(DatePart(Month, GR_Date) As Varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(DatePart(Year, GR_Date) As varchar(4))
```

Comment: That puts the year first. I need the month and then the year.  I switched the order and it works as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: Apologies - copy/paste brain-fart on my part.  Glad that it worked for you.  I've fixed my answer to meet your specification.